# how to write file pdf when i convert html to pdf

Tags: asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

i try to use wkhtmltopdf.exe from server to convert html file to pdf then when process is done. application must to create file pdf . How can i do ? Please help.

this is code

```
string myDocumentsPath = "c:\\wkhtmltopdf.exe ";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(myDocumentsPath, " http://www.website.com/page");

psi.UseShellExecute = false;

psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process myProcess = Process.Start(psi);

myProcess.WaitForExit();

myProcess.Close();
```

Comment: So - what's the problem ? Is there an error ? Can you post more detail please ?

Comment: my problem is when wkhtmltopdf.exe is start then How to create file pdf after that.Are you understand ?